# IIs internal load balancer does not distribute requests evenly

Tags: performance, iis, load-balancing, web-garden

We have windows server 2019.
On IIS server, we have 10 workers.
IIS internal load balancer does not distribute requests  evenly
It means that when IIS received  20 requests, It puts 10 requests on worker 1 and 10 requests on worker 2 and the other 8 workers are idle.
I expected that each worker has 2 requests.
Please help me to correct the config, if exist.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that those 10 requests are easily handled by the one worker process and thus it doesn't need to balance the load out?

Comment: @TimothyG.It doesn't seem like that. Some requests are very time consuming. And other requests are waiting for the completion of that ,while other workers are idle

Comment: may i know what load-balancing algorithm you are using? what is your iis server farm and load balancing setting? what are both of the server site bindings? try to do the health test in iis ARR

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, I use web garden of IIS. its load balance algorithm is configurable?

Comment: Web garden is not load balancing, and you are not even supposed to use it in 2022.

Comment: @LexLi We have an old app that uses it. And after updating Windows Server from 2008 to 2019, I encountered this problem of imbalance in division of requests.

Comment: as Lex li said web garden is not recommended for load balancing instead use is ARR load balancing here is the link you can refer to set up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/configuring-step-3-configure-iis-web-farm-load-balancing